# Why is before(:context) executed for describe ? Ideally it should be executed before Context in spec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to execute a code which should execute before(:context) in the spec.

My spec file :

```
describe "" do
   context 'test context' do
     it 'test' do
     end
   end
end
```

My spec helper.rb file :

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:context) do |example|
    \\ some code which should be executed before context but getting executed during decribe
  end
end
```

Is there any way I can execute code which runs only on before(:context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter as shown in [Filters > Use symbols as metadata](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/hooks/filters#use-symbols-as-metadata) , e.g:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:context, :before_context) do |example|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Only `context` / `describe` blocks specifying that filter will use it:

```
describe "" do
  context 'test context', :before_context do
    it 'test' do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Note that `:before_context` is just an example, you can use any symbol.

Answer (score 0):

`context` and `describe` are actually the same thing (actually they're both aliases for `example_group` as mentioned here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/example-groups/aliasing)

And as you can see in the docs here, there is no `before(:describe)` mentioned: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

So, in summary, it's not possible to do what you're trying to do.